# Changes within gdal_retile.py to set own scale

Tags: c#, python, gdal

I use `gdal_retile.py` script to cut rasters into tiles (rewritten to `C#`). Everything works fine, but I want my script to work in a little different way. What I want is to change the first level scale. I want it to be calculated using the pattern:

```
private const double MetersPerInch = 0.0254;
private const double DPI = 96;

private double GetScale(int meters, int pixels)
{
    return meters/pixels/MetersPerInch*DPI;
}
```

**For example.**

If I get a raster of size `4k x 4k px` and it's `100 km`, then:
`scale = 100000 / 4000 / 0.0254 * 96 = ~94488`
Now I need to find the first scale higher than counted that is a power of 2. In this case it's `1:131072`. And I should set it as my scale for the first level. Next levels' scale should be a power of 2: `[1:262144, 1:524288, 1:1048576, ...]`.

Could any1 help me to modify the script? I don't care about the language (it can be done in `Python` or `C#`).

Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it!

Here's the source code (maybe some1 will need it in the future - be careful, cuz I did my changes in lines `370`, `432` and `433` - if u want to revert my changes  into original, just replace `_scaleFactor` variable by `2` and remove all the `_scaleFactor` calculations): http://pastebin.com/0qUCVk9J